# How to pass accessibility labels with apostrophe in that using frank ios?

Tags: ios, automation, frank

If I have a label with accessibility label "You've done some random task". How will i pass that accessibility label  to view to touch that element. (format required -- view marked:'You've done some random task')

If i give in above format, frank doesn't recognise "You've" and is unable to find the element.
Does anyone know how to pass accessibility labels with apostrophe in that using frank ios?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue and this worked for me

```
view marked:\"You've done some random task\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the special characters with \ should do it.

Try to use:

```
view marked:'You\'ve done some random task'
```